# How to publish archive files to confluence using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use Jenkins to push my .xcarchive archive file on my desktop directory on my macbook to a confluence webpages. Right now, i am using a plugin under the Post-build action to connect my Jenkin to the confluence webpage. However, I was not able to pass my archive file over and encountered this message in the log;

[confluence] Attempting to attach the archived artifacts, but there are no archived artifacts from the job! Check job configuration...
[confluence] Uploading 0 file(s) to Confluence...

I think that my Jenkins application is unable to locate the archive file. Furthermore, I am not certain what is the right direction to tackle this problem. I had tried installing plugin such as Artifact Deployer and Copy artifacts. However, I have no clue on what to input to use the plugin. Can anyone give me some suggestions/advices on what I should do? Thanks!